# Seeing double entries in v$sql for a query run once

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I recently was trying to understand Oracle's data dictionary tables and I noticed something rather strange.

When I run a query like

```
        select * from table where id in (?, ?);
```

just once, I notice that there are 2 rows created in v$sql for the same query. why is that?

However, if i run something like

```
        select * from table where id = 10;
```

I see only a single row being created.

Comment: Are you sure multiple v$sql rows are being created for a single execution of the statement? It's not uncommon for there to be multiple rows created when different explain plans are used in subsequent executions due to bind variable differences etc. This is explained by Tom Kyte here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-may/o38asktom-085659.html

Comment: Do the two rows have different values for `child_number`?